# How to get back external monitor native resolution?

Tags: resolution

I have an external monitor that I use to switch between a dual-boot notebook and a PC via a VGA cable. It was working just fine since I bought it, and it still is on my PC, but since yesterday it's no longer displaying at native resolution in any of my notebook's operating systems. I use Debian 9 and Windows 10 on the notebook, and the last thing I remember doing concerning to this problem is upgrading notebook's graphics card driver with Driver Booster.

The monitor is an AOC (M2470SWD2) at 1920x1080; the graphics cards are a NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT (PC), and an Intel HD Graphics 3000 (Dell Latitude E6420).

When plugging it to PC, its resolution is 1920x1080, but when doing it to the notebook, the resolution is 1366x768 (Windows) or 1024x768 (Debian). Debian also labels it as "Unknown Display".

I've been searching the Internet and I found similar problems that I think might apply to this case. One is that I've corrupted my monitor's EDID by switching (unplugging and plugging) the VGA cable between powered computers. I don't think that is the case because, if it was, I wouldn't be able to get the native resolution on any machine, as EDID is a monitor stuff, right? However, I couldn't fail to notice that when I run the command `xrandr --verbose`, "LVDS" (notebook's integrated monitor) has "EDID" and much more information than VGA: https://pastebin.com/ndEq2RTF. I've also tried to gather information about the VGA's EDID by the commands `modprobe`, `i2cdetect`, `i2cdump`, `./edid-rw`, and `edid-decode`, but this makes it look like the system has nothing in the VGA connector.

Alternatively, it could be a graphics card driver problem due to the Intel HD Graphics 3000's update by Driver Booster, but I think it makes no sense either. If a Windows driver was upgraded, why would Debian be affected? I tried to downgrade to older driver versions on Windows, but it didn't work either.

Does anyone know how to solve this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it by changing to an hdmi-to-dvi cable. So it was neither the drivers nor a corrupted EDID problem. Probably, the VGA bus on my notebook stopped working because it was being plugged in and unplugged. Anyway, I got the 1920x1080 native resolution of my monitor back.